# Wireshark: Display TCP flags in the display

Tags: wireshark

I wish to display the TCP flags as a column in the display window. I add a new column from the Preferences but there is no field type for TCP flags (or more likely - I can't find it). How do I display the TCP flag as a column? Microsoft Network Monitor has an option for this (but can't display the time as seconds since epoch 01-01-1970 which I need). Are there any other .cap file viewers which will allow me to display both these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a custom column and put tcp.flags as the field name.